# Regex for matching single digit preceded by char

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a single digit of a url:

```
www.example.com/api/v1.2/Resource
```

I want to match the '1' but none of the rest. I have come so far:

```
(?i)\/v([0-9]{0,3})\.
```

but this matches `/v1.`

the url will always have the same composition: `api/v[x].[x]/[ResourceName]`

So the rule is:
Match the first digit preceded by a `/v` followed by a `.`

I am using Perl Regex.

Comment: Your  value is in `$1` variable.

Comment: You have to match the /v and the . to be sure that you get the proper string. But then you can access sub groups of your match. A sub group is defined by the parenthesis, so in your case the first group contains what you want. Access i with `$1` or `\1` depending on where you use this regexp. You can have a more precise answer if you explain more what you want to do with this substring (replace, use somewhere else), and what technology you run this regexp with (a text editor replace function, or in some php code?...)

Comment: I Found out how to access the correct values, but appreciate your comment. Never knew there were variables in regex. I am parsing the Regex in Delphi and need to read the version number from the url to call the correct content producer for the endpoint.